# How to import a 3d object file to rotate in SDL

Tags: opengl, 3d, sdl

I have an existing sdl project that rotates a 2d .png image using the arrow keys.  Now I'd like to do the simplest version of that in 3d, but I'm stuck on a basic importing issue.

What file format does the 3d object have to be in?   I have a .step file that I ran Anycad/Autodesk FBX through to create a .fbx file.

According to this, it seems for basic 3d maniupulation, SDL will use openGL under the hood.   However, not sure if what I'm trying to do would be considered simple.    Perhaps they mean just drawing 3d lines?
https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial3:_Rendering_3D_Objects_(C_/SDL)

Any suggestions on how this can be done in SDL, or if it's even possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can be made in SDL but you need to create the loader yourself. SDL doesn't provide 3D methods for manipulating objects and even 3D file formats. You might need to use OpenSceneGraph, Ogre3D or Irrlicht for that unless you want to make the loader yourself with raw OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks!   Seems there's several loader options depending on the 3d file format.  For svg there's paper.js Raphaeljs.. / For obj tehre's syoyo tinyobjloader , Crimild, saitoobjloader, nate robins opengl.    However the 2 that seem most promising is assimp and processing (processing.js).   https://asalga.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/extending-processing-js-with-a-obj-importer-part-4/   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258270/processing-3d-object-obj-import